# Ksh loses data after piping 16K bytes

Tags: solaris, pipe, ksh, stdout, buffer

I recently found that ksh may lose some data after printing more than 16K bytes to the stdout if it is blocked for a couple of seconds.

This `test.sh` script prints out 257*64 (16448) bytes:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
i=0
while [[ i -lt 257 ]]
do
    x=$(file /tmp)
    echo "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDE"
    i=$((i+1))
done |
while read datafile
do
    echo $datafile
done
```

I performed the following test:

```
0 $ ./test.sh | wc -c
   16448
0 $ ./test.sh | (sleep 3; wc -c)
   16384
```

The line `x=$(file /tmp)` seems to affect this behaviour although it does not pipe anything to the second loop.

If I use bash, it works as expected.

It looks like a bug to me in ksh. I am using Solaris 5.10. Is there a solution or workaround for this? What is the root cause of this issue? I guess it might be related to pipe buffer size.

Thanks,
Peter

EDIT:

So running the test with `truss`, I can see an error at writing the last 64 bytes:

```
ioctl(0, I_PEEK, 0x08046B40)                    = 0
    Received signal #18, SIGCLD, in write() [caught]
      siginfo: SIGCLD CLD_EXITED pid=6561 status=0x0000
write(1, " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B".., 64)      Err#4 EINTR
lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00020000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
setcontext(0x08046670)
read(0, 0x0809064C, 1)                          = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETA, 0x08046B18)                    Err#22 EINVAL
```

Running the same script with dtksh looks like below. As Stephane indicated, the failed write is reattempted.

```
ioctl(0, I_PEEK, 0x08046694)                    = 1
read(0, " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B".., 64)       = 64
Received signal #18, SIGCLD, in write() [caught]
  siginfo: SIGCLD CLD_EXITED pid=28276 status=0x0000
write(1, " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B".., 64)      Err#4 EINTR
lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00020000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
waitid(P_ALL, 0, 0x08046500, WEXITED|WTRAPPED|WSTOPPED|WNOHANG) = 0
waitid(P_ALL, 0, 0x08046500, WEXITED|WTRAPPED|WSTOPPED|WNOHANG) Err#10 ECHILD
sigaction(SIGCLD, 0x08046510, 0x08046580)       = 0
setcontext(0x08046430)
write(1, 0x080F0FD8, 64)        (sleeping...)
write(1, " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B".., 64)      = 64
ioctl(0, I_PEEK, 0x08046694)                    = 0
```

Comment: Try running the script with `truss` to see what's going on. small writes are meant to be atomic on pipes, but ksh is known sometimes to use sockets instead of pipes for shell pipes. Also, ksh is known to do wild optimisations that sometimes affect behavior. `truss` will tell you if for instance ksh does one write(2) per echo or if some write(2) fail or are partial. You could also use `lsof` to check whether ksh uses pipes or sockets. FWIW, I can't reproduce it with ksh93u+ on Linux. What version of ksh are you using?

Comment: Yes, I also tried on linux using PD KSH v5.2.14 and it just works fine. Actually I am not sure what Ksh version is shipped with SunOS 5.10, something like this:
`grep -i ver /usr/bin/ksh`
@(#)Version M-11/16/88i

Comment: using /usr/dt/bin/dtksh also works fine.

Comment: running with truss I can see something abnormal, though I don't really know what it means:
    ioctl(0, I_PEEK, 0x08046B40)                    = 0
    Received signal #18, SIGCLD, in write() [caught]
      siginfo: SIGCLD CLD_EXITED pid=6561 status=0x0000
    write(1, " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B".., 64)      Err#4 EINTR
    lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00020000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
    setcontext(0x08046670)
    read(0, 0x0809064C, 1)                          = 0
    ioctl(0, TCGETA, 0x08046B18)                    Err#22 EINVAL

Comment: It would make more sense to add that information to the question. Also, it would be helpful to see whether it's the first echo or the second that gets interrupted (like change the second to "echo x$datafile"). It looks like a ksh bug indeed. I suspect ksh doesn't wait for the "file" command to terminate (just wait until EOF when reading its output), and the SIGCLD are handled later on. It's fine in the general case, but when writing to a full pipe, the `write` for that echo is blocking so likely to be interrupted by the SIGCLD. Doing `(echo ...)`, that is use a subshell, might WA the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Stephane. Indeed, using a subshell when doing echo provides a workaround to this issue. And why does it work :) ? Because ksh waits until the subshell completes?

Comment: No, because it's the parent that gets the SIGCLD, not the subshell.

Comment: incidentally, /usr/bin/ksh, on Solaris 11 (11/11 + SRU 13.4) works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That indeed looks like a bug in `ksh`.

What I suspect is that in

```
x=$(file /tmp)
```

`ksh` spawns a new process to run the `file` command and reads its output through a pipe, and doesn't wait for its termination (as would all modern shells, including modern versions of ksh), but that command returns as soon as EOF is reached when reading from that pipe.

That behaviour could be confirmed by running:

```
ksh -c 'x=$(exec sh -c "echo foo;exec >&-; sleep 10"); echo "$x"'
```

And check whether `ksh` returns immediately after having output `foo` or after 10 seconds.

If that's the case, then that means the `file` command will terminate and cause a SIGCLD to be sent to its parent (the shell), **after** the `x=...` command has returned.

The shell is meant to handle those SIGCLD to enquire about the death of its child. If the shell has a child running in the background, it should be ready for it death happening at any moment. That SIGCLD signal, just like any non-ignored signal would cause a blocking system call to be *interrupted*. The shell should be ready for that to happen, either by *blocking* the signal while doing a system call that may be interrupted, or by reattempting the interrupted system call after having handled the signal.

In this case, it looks like none of that is happening. Most of the time, the `write` system call performed by ksh about running the builtin `echo` returns immediately, so there's no chance for it to be interrupted, but after the pipe that stdout points to is full, the `write` system call ends up blocking and that's when it gets interrupted by the SIGCLD. And ksh doesn't reattempt it which is the bug.

We can see the same behavior even on Linux if we run

```
strace -e write ksh -c 'i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 2000 ]; do : &
  echo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  i=$(($i+1)); done' | (sleep 3; wc)
```

Then we see:

```
write(1, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 61) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
write(1, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 61...
```

It's the same, the terminating `:` command causes the blocking `write` system call to be interrupted, but this time, the `write` is reattempted.

A work around could consist in avoiding command substitutions before a call to a builtin `echo`, or make sure the `write` is done by a different process from the one getting the SIGCLD, for instance by running the `echo` command in a subshell:

```
(echo "012...")
```

**EDIT**: A closer look at the `truss` output reveals it's the trace from the second loop which is meant to run in a separate process from the one running the other loop, so shouldn't be getting the SIGCLD from the death of the `file` commands. It could get one SIGCLD though, from the termination of the subshell running the first loop.

Also if, as your test result suggests, ksh does wait for the processes spawned for command substitution, then the SIGCLD signals received can't be explained by asynchronous termination of the `file` command.

What looks more likely is that the outer pipe gets full, but not the pipe between the two while loops, the SIGCLD is received during the blocking `echo` in the second loop and comes from the termination of the first loop. So, a more efficient workaround would be to run the second loop in a subshell rather than every `echo` command in it.

```
while ...; done | (while ...;done)
```

Comment: The test command above seems to work and returns 'foo' after 10s. However, using dtksh instead of ksh I can see that the `write` is reattempted after the SIGCLD. And as you stated, this is not done by ksh and so it fails. I will append an trace log fragment of dtksh to the question for reference.

Comment: (a `$` was missing which I've now added). If it outputs "foo" after 10s, then that means my interpretation is wrong, that ksh does wait for the process spawned by the command substitution and therefore shouldn't receive the SIGCLD in the middle of the next "write" system call. The full output of `truss -f`  would tell us what's really going on.

Comment: yes, running the second while in a subshell also works. The full output of `truss -f` is 2.3M and unfortunately I don't see a way to add attachments here. I could paste the last 5000 lines here: http://pastebin.com/YCp12e80